# Java Custom Serialization throwing EOFException

Tags: java, serialization

The following code throws an EOFException during deserialization [in line size = in.readInt();] and I am bewildered why this is occurring.

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.ObjectStreamException;
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class ArrayList2 implements Serializable
{
    transient String [] bs = new String[100];
    transient int size;

    // custom serialiation (the physical structure is not equal to logical structure)
    private void writeObject(java.io.ObjectOutputStream out)
            throws IOException
    {
        out.defaultWriteObject();
        out.write(size);
        for (int i=0;i<size;i++)
            out.writeObject(bs[i]);
    }

    private void readObject(java.io.ObjectInputStream in)
            throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException {

        in.defaultReadObject();
        size = in.readInt(); // ERROR OCCURS HERE
        bs = new String[size];

        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
            bs[i] = (String) in.readObject();

    }
}
```

Interestingly, when the size is not transient and I do not read or write the size in readObject and writeObject the deserialization works fine.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
out.write(size);
```

The problem is here. This only writes one byte. To be symmetrical with your reading code, it should be

```
out.writeInt(size);
```